# Accessing environment variables in Linux service conf files

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables, dhcp

I have a bunch of environment variables in `/etc/environment` in a Debian OS. I would like to use some of these environment variables in various configuration files, for example, `/etc/service/service.conf`. Typically I can use the variables, defined in `/etc/environment` like below.

`/etc/environment`:

`MYVAR="Some value"`

`script.sh`:

`echo ${MYVAR}`

Typically I can use `export MYVAR="Some value"` which the Apache configuration files can pick up, but other services such as dhcp (/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf) do not.

What are my options in this case?

Answer (score 0):

/etc/environment is not system-wide configuration file. just use systemd-system.conf